# Where to set module specific global variables and how

Tags: php, kohana-3

I'm building a somewhat large application using kohana 3.1. I'm trying to set module-wide variables, like definitions. It will be some arrays with key => values.

To give an example, if it was a user module I would like to set the available profiles like

```
$profiles = array(
  'user' => array('desc'=>'common user','access'=>'1'),
  'jonhdoe' => array('desc'=>'not logged user','access'=>0)
);
```

and use the $profiles all over my module but not on the outside. Should I set it in init.php? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use protected properties in your module class.

```
protected profiles = array();
```

somewhere in the module:

```
$this->profiles = array(
  'user' => array('desc'=>'common user','access'=>'1'),
  'jonhdoe' => array('desc'=>'not logged user','access'=>0)
);
```

And you can access this array ONLY from module class or its child-classes.

Comment: ok, that sound cool. I have controllers, models and views inside the module. so, extending the main module class will have that var available. Cool! Thank you